# Variable annotation used before being Initialised

Tags: objective-c, swift

Hello below is code for the CCHMapClusterController. Im trying to rewrite this function to Swift, but I keep getting this error:

"Variable annotation used before being Initialised"

on the line:
clusterAnnotation = annotation

I have no clue in Objective C, could someone check if I did the last few lines properly?

Objective C:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:    (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView;

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:CCHMapClusterAnnotation.class]) {
    static NSString *identifier = @"clusterAnnotation";

    ClusterAnnotationView *clusterAnnotationView = (ClusterAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (clusterAnnotationView) {
        clusterAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;
    } else {
        clusterAnnotationView = [[ClusterAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        clusterAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }

    CCHMapClusterAnnotation *clusterAnnotation = (CCHMapClusterAnnotation *)annotation;
    clusterAnnotationView.count = clusterAnnotation.annotations.count;
    clusterAnnotationView.blue = (clusterAnnotation.mapClusterController == self.mapClusterControllerBlue);
    clusterAnnotationView.uniqueLocation = clusterAnnotation.isUniqueLocation;
    annotationView = clusterAnnotationView;
}

return annotationView;
}
```

Swift Code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        // return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    var annotationView : MKAnnotationView?


    if annotation is CCHMapClusterAnnotation {
      //  let a : clusterAnnotationView = annotation as clusterAnnotationView

        let identifier: NSString = "clusterAnnotation"
        var clusterAnnotationView = (mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier as String)) as? ClusterAnnotationView!

        if (clusterAnnotationView != nil) {
            clusterAnnotationView!.annotation = annotation
        } else {
            clusterAnnotationView = ClusterAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "clusterAnnotation")
            clusterAnnotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        }

        var clusterAnnotation : CCHMapClusterAnnotation;
        var annotation : CCHMapClusterAnnotation
        clusterAnnotation = annotation
        clusterAnnotationView.count = clusterAnnotation.annotations.count
        clusterAnnotationView!.blue = (clusterAnnotation.mapClusterController == self.mapClusterControllerBlue);
        clusterAnnotationView!.uniqueLocation = clusterAnnotation.isUniqueLocation();
        annotationView = clusterAnnotationView

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these lines:

```
var clusterAnnotation : CCHMapClusterAnnotation;
var annotation : CCHMapClusterAnnotation
clusterAnnotation = annotation
```

two variables are declared but not initialized so you get that warning.

In addition, it's also declaring a new local variable `annotation` that has the same name as the existing `annotation` parameter.  You may be getting a warning or error for that as well.

If you're trying to convert this Objective-C line:

```
CCHMapClusterAnnotation *clusterAnnotation = 
    (CCHMapClusterAnnotation *)annotation;
```

which is ***casting*** the `annotation` parameter as a `CCHMapClusterAnnotation`, then a possible Swift version is:

```
let clusterAnnotation = annotation as? CCHMapClusterAnnotation
```

However, you could also combine the annotation class check you have above (`if annotation is ...`) with this casted assignment:

```
if let clusterAnnotation = annotation as? CCHMapClusterAnnotation {
    ...
}
```